How to link the Plugin-functions to the created submenu in a QGIS PlugIn-menu?
Just some context: I have created two stand-alone plugins based on the code of the QGIS-Plugin-builder. For these I would like to create one menu from which you can then select one plugin to run it.
Based on this discussion Handling multiple QGIS Plugins in one custom menu and code snippet I managed to create a new menu-point in the qgis tool bar ('LK-tools') with a submenu 'Reformat to LK-names'.

However, when I click on the submenu it doesn't run the plugin, so it seems I still need to link the submenu with my functions. How can I do this, what do I need to adjust in my code?
This is my code:
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QMenu
import qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets as QtWidgets
from qgis.core import *

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from reformat_lk.resources import *

# Import the code for the dialog
from reformat_lk.reformat_LK_dialog import ReformatToLKNamesDialog
import os.path


class ReformatToLKNames:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'ReformatToLKNames_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Reformat to LK-names')


        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('ReformatToLKNames', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    
    def initGui(self):
        # Check if the menu exists and get it
        self.menu = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QMenu, '&LK-tools')

        # If the menu does not exist, create it!
        if not self.menu:
            self.menu = QMenu('&LK-tools', self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar())
            self.menu.setObjectName('&LK-tools')
            actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
            lastAction = actions[-1]
            self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu(lastAction, self.menu)

        # Finally, add your action to the menu
        self.action = QAction(QIcon(f'{self.plugin_dir}/LK_symbol.PNG'), "Reformat To LK-Names", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.menu.addAction(self.action)


    def unload(self):
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&Reformat to LK-names'),  # here is still the name from the code in the constructor method
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        menu_actions = []
        for action in self.menu.actions():
            menu_actions.append(action)
            if len(menu_actions) <= 1:
                self.menu.deleteLater()



    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = ReformatToLKNamesDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()

        # If OK was pressed
        if result:
            self.mainfunction()

---- UPDATE
When I take over the also the initGUI completely from the referenced discussion like this:
    def initGui(self):
        icon_path = f'{self.plugin_dir}/LK_symbol.PNG'
        #check if the menu already exists
        self.menu = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QMenu, u'&LK-Tools')
        # if not create it
        if not self.menu:
            self.menu = QMenu(self.iface.mainWindow())
            self.menu.setObjectName(u'&LK-Tools')
            self.menu.setTitle(u'&LK-Tools')

        # create the action
        self.action = QAction(QIcon(icon_path), 'ReformatToLKNames', self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.setObjectName('ReformatToLKNames')
        self.action.setWhatsThis('ReformatToLKNames')
        self.action.setStatusTip('ReformatToLKNames')
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)

        self.menu.addAction(self.action)

        menuBar = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar()
        menuBar.insertMenu(self.iface.firstRightStandardMenu().menuAction(), self.menu)

I get the error AttributeError: 'ReformatToLKNames' object has no attribute 'dlg'. I'm an absolute beginner with building PlugIns, but it seems that the PlugIn is wrongly referenced?

self.action.triggered.connect(self.run). It was in the code that you copied and pasted from.

Hi @BenW Thank you for helping, but I didn't copy the full script, so it differs! When I add self.action.triggered.connect(self.run) below self.menu.addAction(self.action) I can click on the submenu, but unfortunately I get the error  AttributeError: 'ReformatToLKNames' object has no attribute 'dlg'. I guess I create the action wrongly?

No! That error is coming from the run() method (because it is now actually being called when you trigger the action). The problem is that you have deleted the line self.first_start = True from the end of the initGui() method. Therefore, when run() is executed, self.first_start does not evaluate to True, so the self.dlg attribute (dialog class instance) is not created. Therefore, the plugin class has no attribute dlg, hence the error.

Thank you so much, this worked (when I add self.first_start = True)! I'm very new to creating PlugIns (and Qt) and only now starting to get to understand the base code.

No problem. You can actually simplify the code a bit if you just create the dialog instance in the plugin class constructor, like in my other answer. Since the basic setup of a QGIS Python gui-based plugin is like 95% PyQt gui programming, you would probably get a lot of benefit from going over some intro PyQt tutorials.

This tutorial series looks like it covers a lot of the basic stuff you have been asking about for example this section goes into the basics of toolbars, menus & actions.

@BenW Thank you! This is very helpful! I will look into the tutorials!
